# How to reset or change the passphrase for git

Tags: git

I need to change my passphrase for git. How to change this. I have found how to change passphrase in github. but there is no solution to reset passphrase for git.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Git itself has no passphrase. Are you maybe referring to your SSH key?

Comment: If yes, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-ssh-changing-passphrase/

Comment: I actually I meant SSH key. Thank you for the informative link , and from that, I have changed the passphrase.